# Gaussian rolling weights pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, signal-processing

Suppose that I have a `pandas` series of data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000
srs = pd.Series(np.random.random(n))
```

I wish to now roll a Gaussian filter through this data such that the weights look like:

```
window = 100

x = np.arange(window)

mu = 60
sigma = 0.2

y = np.exp(-(x-mu)**2 / 2*sigma**2) / np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2)

plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

That is to say, for each `window` of length `100` the 60th entry has the maximum weight and the other entries decay as per the Gaussian formulation.

Is this possible with `.rolling()`?

Comment: Once you weight each element, pandas Series/DataFrame rolling method requires you an aggregate function. Are you looking for a weighted sum/mean?

Comment: I guess a `mean` would work yeah

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.average](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) to take a weighted mean:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 1000
window_size = 100

srs = pd.Series(np.random.random(n))

mu = 60
sigma = 0.2
x = np.arange(window_size)
weights = np.exp(-(x-mu)**2 / 2*sigma**2) / np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2)

srs.rolling(window).apply(lambda wndw: np.average(wndw, weights=weights))
```

This is the same as:

```py
srs.rolling(window).apply(lambda wndw: (wndw*weights).sum()/weights.sum())
```

Remark that this will break if you try to pass a `min_periods` less than `window` since `np.average` requires `a` and `weights` to have the same length.

Comment: I believe the weights are inverted

Comment: Maybe it is just a poor choice of variable naming! your weight is called `y`, the temp variable I called `w` was to denote the window you are considering. I will rename it and clarify it.